# How to verify ownership on google of a react website hosted on Vercel

Tags: html, reactjs, vercel

How do I verify a react.js website hosted on Vercel? On google Ownership verification page I've added a new property and was given an html file to upload to my server in order to verify my website but now is it just a matter of uploading the html file to the root of my project? And the head tag, where would I include it?
[image]

Or is there another procedure for verifying react websites?

Comment: Can you show the whole picture?

Answer (score 0):

React is at the end a static Javascript in a html file better know as SPA(Single Page Application) so just put the tag `<meta tag name="google-site-verification" ... >` on index.html inside `<head>` tag in your public folder and that's it.